# Deleting temporary directory

Tags: java, servlets, temporary-directory

I found some code on here for creating temporary directories in Java.

```
public static File createTempDirectory() throws IOException
{
    final File temp;
    temp = File.createTempFile("temp", Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));

    if(!(temp.delete()))
    {
        throw new IOException("Could not delete temp file: " + temp.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    if(!(temp.mkdir()))
    {
        throw new IOException("Could not create temp directory: " + temp.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return temp;
}
```

How can I at the end of my servlet's life a handle on this temporary directory and delete it?

Comment: How about keeping a static reference to it?

Comment: @Matten: a static field? Bad idea! What if two instances create temp directories at the same time?

Comment: Ok... a non-static reference? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First:

Don't use this method of creating a temporary directory! **It is unsafe!** Use the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) method [`Files.createTempDir()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#createTempDir%28%29) instead (or re-implement it manually, if you don't want to use Guava). The reason is described in its JavaDoc:

> A common pitfall is to call [`createTempFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), delete the file and create a directory in its place, but this leads a race condition which can be exploited to create security vulnerabilities, especially when executable files are to be written into the directory.

Regarding your real question:

You need to delete the directory manually, which means you need to keep track of all directories you create (for example in a `Collection<File>`) and delete them when you know for sure that they are not longer needed.